# Using context.Database.Log in MVC web app

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, logging

Using the guide [here](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/), I'm trying to log the SQL generated by my MVC web application.

The guide uses the line:

```
context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
```

Which obviously doesn't work with a web application.  The guide described the Log property:

> The DbContext.Database.Log property can be set to a delegate for any
>   method that takes a string.

And it's this I don't understand, delegates just confuse me. How can I use this EF6 feature?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using a delegate allows you to do write any function taking a string.  As a very simple logging to a file, you could do the following:

```
context.Database.Log = message => File.AppendText("C:\\mylog.txt").WriteLine(message);
```

In a web environment, you may wish to use Trace to log this information:

```
context.Database.Log = message => Trace.WriteLine(message);
```

You can see more examples of using delegates on the [MSDN page on Anonymous Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

To write your logs to a file, try this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var logFile = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\log.txt");
    context.Database.Log = logFile.Write;

    // Execute your queries here
    // ....

    logFile.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print it in Debug window:

```
dbContext.Database.Log = message => Debug.Write(message);
```