# Finding where nullable long == null in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This might be a duplicate but nothing I've found up till now has solved this issue for me.

I'm trying to do a simple LINQ method

```
List<MyObject> unusedObject = _context.MyObjects.Where(o => o.CreatorUserId == null).ToList();
```

CreatorUserId is a nullable long. 
In my database I'm seeing at least 10 objects with CreatorUserId = NULL but this call returns 0 objects.

I'm using EF6 in which I thought all such null issues were fixed

Edit - MyObject

```
[Table("MyObjects")]
public partial class MyObject
{
    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public long MyObjectId { get; set; }

    public long? CreatorUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatorUser { get; set; }

}
```

Edit 2 -trace log

```
SELECT 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C1], 
    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C2]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: Is it working if you try o.CreatorUserId.Equals(null) ?

Comment: Please show the `MyObjects`

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299038/using-context-database-log-in-mvc-web-app read the sql that EF is creating to see where things are not matching your expected sql.

Comment: Try to insert .Select(s => s). If that doesn't  work try to break your code in two parts. It uses .list () just in the second part.

Comment: @mybirthname unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: @GiladGreen add MyObject, nothing too special there

Comment: For some reason EF thinks your field is non nullable and is generating fake empty SQL. Are you using Code First - fluent configuration or ?

Comment: @IvanStoev using code first, i'm thinking now though i might have messed up my migrations at some point, this is still not in prod so i'll just re-create migrations when i get home

Comment: This query shows that EF is convinced that `CreatorUserId` can't possibly be null in the database (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18970039/861716)), so I think EF has wrong mapping info (although that's not apparent from the code you show).

Comment: @GertArnold I think you're right, looks like this is happening to me. Similar to the comments this likely a result of an incorrect done attempt on my end to make my CreateUserId column nullable

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<MyObject> unusedObject = _context.MyObjects.Where(o => o.CreatorUserId.HasValue == false).ToList();
```

If it's still zero results then either MyObjects contains no data or CreatorUserId always has a value